# how to DEPLOY a RAD generated WEBSERIVCE project EAR on WEBSPHERE

Tags: deployment, websphere, ear

I have generated a webservice project using RAD/Eclipse and I want to generate a `ear` file of it and deploy it to `WebShere`.

After deploying the `ear` file in `WebShere`, the application server does not recognize it as a web service and the `WSDL` is not coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the web service is not recognized...! Try verifying your ear
Uninstall the previously deployed and clean up your temp folders and do the re-install